# Google Drive API insert/retrieve files using Java

Tags: google-drive-api

This question is regarding using Google Drive API. How do we pass the location where the files that are getting inserted are stored? (like store files in a particular folder)? 
When I insert a file, it goes to the root. Instead I want to store it in a particular location. Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ID of the parent folder into an array element of parents. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: We could complete it. Thanks,